# HTML5 webpage linking to another webpage on my hard drive

Tags: html

I searched both in stackoverflow and online for an answer to my question but everything I seemed to find, did not work. I have two webpages both saved in the same folder on my local hard drive. I am trying to link the first webpage to the second webpage. I created the following link attempting to do this,

Noah's First Day

Using Google Chrome, I get the following error message when I click on the link in my first webpage (attempting to link to the second webpage);

This webpage is not found

ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

I have tried changing my protocol from file:/// to ftp:/// to http:///. In each case, I get the same message. Can anyone help me in determining what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you access the first page via a web server?

Comment: No. I am fairly new to html and css but. I created the page using notepad on my desktop. I am then saving that file/page in a folder in my local drive. When I open the main notepad file/page using Google Chrome. My first page and link displays fine. But when I click on the link in my first webpage, I get that error message. The code representing the link in my first notepad/page file is <li><a href="file://C:\Users\Brian\Desktop\Noah.txt">Noah's First Day</a></li>

Comment: Does it work with IE?

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: It didn't do any better in IE. Similar error. Sure, here is the code.

Comment: Are you sure that the file path and the name is correct? Try to open the file in the explorer and confirm path and name.